# C# constructor question, received parent class

Tags: c#

There is a bit of C# syntax that I don't understand.

I am on the receiving end of a couple of classes.  Simplified, let's say it's this

```
public class ParentClass
    {
    public ParentClass();
    public RandomEnumerated Random_Enumerated; //No get/set. Relevant?
    }

public class ReceivedClass : ParentClass
    {
    public ReceivedClass();
    public char Random_Field { get; set; }
    }
```

When I do this

```
public class ExtendedReceivedClass : ReceivedClass
{
    public ExtendedReceivedClass();
    public char A_New_Random_Field_of_My_Own { get; set; }
}
```

I get hit by the error
ExtendedReceivedClass.ExtendedReceivedClass() must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial FuelTaCSClient

So instead of being able to do what the parental classes do

```
public ParentClass();
or
public ReceivedClass();
```

I have to do this

```
public ExtendedReceivedClass () {}
```

So my question is

a

Is the "public ReceivedClass();" in ReceivedClass the constructor? Same for ParentClass.

b

If it is, why can they do a shortcut version but I can't

or

if it isn't, what is it?

Comment: could you please provide a _correct_ simplification that actually reproduces the behavior you're getting? because with the code you provided, you get your error message in `ParentClass` and `ReceivedClass`

Comment: What does "on the receiving end of a couple of classes" mean? The code you posted for `ParentClass` won't compile either. You need a body (which can be empty as you did: `{ }`).

Comment: you can [omit parameterless constructors](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rcP0hn) when they do nothing and there is no other constructors

Comment: I believe that you have too many levels of inheritance with concrete classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*I am on the receiving end of a couple of classes*" -- I think you're looking at those classes using Visual Studio's "Go To Definition" or similar, and they're defined in another DLL?

You'll notice that Visual Studio is showing you method signatures, but not the bodies of the methods: when all it has is a DLL, it's easy to get the signatures, but harder to get the original C# code which was used to build the DLL. This is just intended to give you an overview of what methods are available, and it's not supposed to be valid C#.

`public ParentClass();` is not valid C#. It's the signature of a constructor (showing that there's a public parameterless constructor), but when you define a constructor in C# you need to provide a body:

```
public ParentClass()
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to accept this as the answer because it seems to make the most sense.  I have no trouble believing that when I ask VS to tell me what is in a parent class that it will give me an abbreviated and slightly askew version of what's actually in it.

I am doing a hard search for the parent class by name using a third-party search tool and if I see anything that either affirms or refutes this conclusion I will post an update.

Thank you to everyone who helped!  And canton7 - thank you and have this upvote!

Comment: Found the actual text using a search program, and yes - there it is...  "ReceivedClass() {}"